# What is the difference between these two future conditionals?

Tags: meaning, conditionals

> If you lend me some money I will start a business.

or,

> If you will lend me some money I will start a business.

What is the difference between the meaning of these two future conditionals?

Comment: Without any context there is no difference in meaning, but the first is more colloquial.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian what context do you want?

Answer (score 0):

We would usually say the first. Eg:

- If I lend you some money what will you do?
- If you lend me some money I will start a business.

The second might be used when the first 'will' needs to be emphasized. Eg:

- If I refuse to lend you any money, what then?
- I'll become an alcoholic. But if you *will* lend me some money I will start a business.